# class std::vector has no member named

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct coffeeBean
{   
    string name; 
    string country;
    int strength;
};  

std::vector<coffeeBean> coffee_vec[4];

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    coffee_vec[1].name;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code I get `'class std::vector<coffeeBean>' has no member named 'name'`
I thought we can access the struct this way. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you declare a vector you need to use `()` or `{}`, not `[]` like you do with an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating an array of four vectors, not a vector with four elements.

In your code, `coffee_vec[1]` refers to a `vector<coffeeBean>` object, not a `coffeeBean` object.

Comment: Good answer for "Why am not able to access struct from vector?" and "Am I doing something wrong?" Maybe you could also answer the implicit "How do I make it better?"

Answer (score 6):

with `coffe_vec[1]` you are not accessing an instance of `coffeBean` but an instance of `std::vector<coffeBean>` because `coffe_vec` is an array of vectors. If you want to access `coffeBean` elements you need to call for example `coffe_vec[1][0]` which wouldn't be good in your case because all vectors in your array are empty.

Maybe you wanted to create a vector with 4 elements, that would look like that:

```
std::vector<coffeBean> coffe_vec(4);
```

or use `{ }`

Answer (score 1):

a vector can push and pop objects as it can with built-in data.

if we create only one vector we can push in it datta:

```
std::vector<int> vecInt;    // vector of integers
std::vector<int> vecInt[4]; // an array of vectors to integers

so the array of vectors is like a multi-dimensional array. so to access the data we double the subscript operator `[][]`:

vecInt[0].push_back(5);
cout << vecInt[0][0]; // the first for first vector in the array and the second index is for the first data in the first vector in the array.
```

in your example you have an array to vectors to struct coffeebeen:

```
std::vector<coffeeBean> coffee_vec[4];

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    coffeeBean cofB = { "Raindrop7", "England", 5 };
    coffee_vec[0].push_back(cofB); // push the object in the first vector in the array

    cout << (coffee_vec[0][0]).name  << endl;


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```